# Constraint check with variable values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called `TEST`:

```
PAR                    CHLD                   
---------------------- ---------------------- 
1                      2                      
1                      3                      
1                      4                      
2                      5                      
3                      6
```

The `PAR` and `CHLD` column form a composite primary key.

My requirement is that if I'm updating a value in the `CHLD` column it should only accept any of the existing values in the column.

This should fail because value 7 is not in column `CHLD`:

```
UPDATE TEST SET CHLD = 7 WHERE PAR = 3;
```

This should succeed because value 4 is in column `CHLD`

```
UPDATE TEST SET CHLD = 4 WHERE PAR = 3;
```

Please note I cannot have check constraint for fixed values as I dont know the list of values during table design.

Comment: Hi Prabhu, can you explain your question in details actually i am not getting, mainly what you want as output?

Comment: In your example you say that CHLD contains 1, 2, 5, and 4, and that an update from 4 to 5 should not be allowed, but an update from 4 to 2 should be allowed. What is different between updating 4 to 5 and updating 4 to 2? Both 5 and 2 are in the list of existing values. Please edit your question and add further explanation of what you're trying to accomplish. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my comments. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another table, e.g. CHILDREN, which contains the valid values (2,3,4,5,6). Then add a referential constraint from your TEST table to CHILDREN.

Comment: Hope I have no choice other than having a table that stores list of value and having a referential constraint to that table